# Split string into array using integers as separator

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split the string:

`The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat`

into the array:

`["cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"]`

Can anybody help me with the `regex` to use as the `split()` separator?

Comment: Just a typo or don't you want the first `The` to be included in your result?

Comment: Show us your tries and why aren't they working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are either two ways to achieve it. The first one is to use the `.split` method:

```
var str = 'The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat';
var array = str.split(/\s+\d+\.\s+/g);
```

Or using `.match` method:

```
var str = 'The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat';
var array = str.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
```

I personally prefer the second way, since it works perfectly with blank padded strings like `"
 My cat "`

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Thanks to everybody else too.

Answer (score 0):

```
'The 1. cat 2. sat 3. on 4. the 5. mat'.split(/\s*\d\.\s*/)
```

working as per requirement

```
 #=> ["The", "cat", "sat", "on", "the", "mat"]
```